# How to remove only parentheses ?? contents in pandas column of (A) to A

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_MCE['Composition'] = df_MCE['Composition'].str.replace(r", \(.*\)",""),
```

where

`df_MCE['Composition'] = (A,B)`

resulting in `NaN`

Comment: `(.*)` removes everything. Please format your code and question properly.

Comment: "df_MCE['Composition'].dtypes"  is
"dtype('O')"

Answer (score 1):

As parenthesis are regex meta-characters, you have to escape them with backslash.  You can use:

```
df_MCE['Composition'] = df_MCE['Composition'].str.replace(r"\(|\)", "")
```

### Edit

You can convert the column to string first before removing parenthesis, as follows:

```
df_MCE['Composition'] = df_MCE['Composition'].astype(str).str.replace(r"\(|\)", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: still resulting in NaN

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing `.*`, just replace parentheses one by one-

```
df_MCE['Composition'] = df_MCE['Composition'].astype(str).str.replace("(", "")
df_MCE['Composition'] = df_MCE['Composition'].astype(str).str.replace(")", "")
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: You need to convert the column to string. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict=['(Cr,Mn)']

df_MCE=pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['Composition'])
```

above temporary `df_MCE`   is working based on your reply

However, my pandas generated by pymatgen toolkit is not working.